# Meteor - color highlight table row when date=today

Tags: meteor

i would like to highlight the date if match.datetime if equal to today, May I have some hints?

in .html

```
{{#each match in matches}}
<tr class="center aligned"  bgcolor= "red">
    <td>
            {{match.datetime}}
    </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

in .js

```
Template.List_matches_page.helpers({
    matches() {
        return Matches.find({}, {sort: {datetime: -1}});
    },
});
```

Comment: hightlight row <tr bgcolo="red"> if match.datetime = today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a helper for that:

```html
{{#each match in matches}}
<tr class="center aligned"  bgcolor= "red">
    <td class="{{#if isToday match.datetime}}color-bg{{/if}}">
            {{match.datetime}}
    </td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

```js
const now = new Date()
const isToday = (date) => 
  date.getFullYear() === now.getFullYear() &&
  date.getMonth() === now.getMonth() &&
  date.getDate() === now.getDate()


Template.List_matches_page.helpers({
    matches() {
        return Matches.find({}, {sort: {datetime: -1}});
    },
    isToday(date) {
      return isToday(date)
    }
});
```

If you have many places in your code, that require this check, you should rather use `Template.registerHelper` to avoid duplicate code in your templates: https://www.blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-registerHelper

Comment: return nothing, i can confirm the match.datetime output is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM", do you have any hints?

Comment: when i use console.log to debug, get this error.
    isToday(date) {
        console.log(isToday(date));
    }

Exception in template helper: TypeError: date.getFullYear is not a function

Comment: Are you sure `match.datetime` is a `Date` instance? If not, you need to wrap it into a `Date` before passing to `isToday`.

Comment: it is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM", May i know how to wrap it into Date? As it inside the Matches.find query. I have no idea.

Comment: If you have created the collection in Meteor your should be able to pass dates simply as date objects to the db then you never have to parse string to date

Comment: Yes, but how to fix this issue?